# UIElement.InvalidateVisual on Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've made a custom UIElement that need to update its appearance when certain DependencyProperties are changed. But I can't find the InvalidateVisual-method on UIElement-class. Why has it been removed in the WP7-API? Is there a work around?

---

**Update:**

The problem I'm having seem to be related to that custom shape-derivatives is'nt supported at all in Silverlight/WP7! I have to re-think this.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation of [UIElement.InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) you will find it states:

> This method is not generally called from your application code. The
>   WPF framework-level layout system does its own handling of changes in
>   the visual tree of an element, and would be calling the equivalent of
>   this method when necessary already.

When your dependency property changes, simply update the state of your UI. For example, if you have a rectangle where its width is dependant on the dependency property value, simply change the width within your dependency property event change handler. The rendering framework will perform the required invalidation for you.

Comment: InvalidateVisual doesn't exist in the WP7-API. And since FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsRender doesn't exist either I have to trigger some kind of refresh manually.

Comment: Correct, there is no metadata as in WPF. just update your UI directly